# Using assisted injection create a complex dependency tree

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice, assisted-inject

I have recently learned about the *AssistedInject* extension to Guice and I thought it would be a nice solution to some design issues that I have. Unfortunately it seems that this solution is limited to just a one level assisted injection. Here comes an illustration of my problem - let's say we have three classes:

```
public class AImpl implements A{

    @AssistedInject
    public AImpl(@Assisted Integer number, B b){

    }
}

public class BImpl implements B {

}

public class CImpl implements C {
    @AssistedInject
    public CImpl(A a){

    }
}
```

a factory interface:

```
public interface CFactory {
    C create(Integer number);
}
```

and a module:

```
public class ABCModule extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(A.class).to(AImpl.class);
        bind(B.class).to(BImpl.class);

        install(new FactoryModuleBuilder().implement(C.class, CImpl.class).build(CFactory.class));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Guice.createInjector(new ABCModule()).getInstance(CFactory.class).create(123);
    }

}
```

Above fails with following stacktrace:

> Exception in thread "main" com.google.inject.CreationException: Guice
>   creation errors:
>
> 1) Could not find a suitable constructor in stack.AImpl. Classes must
>   have either one (and only one) constructor annotated with @Inject or a
>   zero-argument constructor that is not private.   at
>   stack.AImpl.class(AImpl.java:12)   at
>   stack.ABCModule.configure(ABCModule.java:14)
>
> 2) stack.CImpl has @AssistedInject constructors, but none of them
>   match the parameters in method stack.CFactory.create().  Unable to
>   create AssistedInject factory.   while locating stack.CImpl   while
>   locating stack.C   at stack.CFactory.create(CFactory.java:1)
>
> 2 errors  at
>   com.google.inject.internal.Errors.throwCreationExceptionIfErrorsExist(Errors.java:435)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.initializeStatically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:154)
>     at
>   com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:106)
>     at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:95)    at
>   com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:72)     at
>   com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:62)     at
>   stack.ABCModule.main(ABCModule.java:21)

This obviously means that I want too much from the extension - I hoped that the injector will search deep down in the dependecy tree searching for the @Assisted dependency. Is there any way to do this kind of assisted injection or do I need to implement my factory by myself?

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a couple problems. You need to inject an "A" into "C" but your factory is set up to inject an integer

```
public interface CFactory {
    C create(Integer number);
}
```

Also I don't think there is an `@AssistedInject` annotation provided by Guice. Use `@Inject` on the constructor instead, and mark the params you want to pass in with `@Assisted`

Comment: It has no problems (except it is basically not possible to do it like this in Guice). The A and B are supposed to be injected automatically by Guice while I wanted to get a factory that parametrizes the whole class system with an Integer parameter (applied by Guice to A constructor). And yes, there is @AssistedInject annotation [docs](http://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/index.html?com/google/inject/assistedinject/AssistedInject.html), otherwise the stacktrace would look a bit different.

Comment: I see, you wanted the Integer to be passed to the nearest dependency which needs it I guess. Your constructor takes an "A" and your factory is passing it an "Integer" so I was explaining one of errors, if that's not what you meant.